# Error import module when invoking serverless lambda locally - python3.8

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am using the serverless Framework to deploy AWS lambdas.

**Repository structure**

```
parser/
  __init__.py
  utils.py
lambda.py
serverless.yml
```

I have the following config :
severless.yml

```
service: extract

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  timeout: 300

functions:
  test:
    handler: lambda.handle
package:
    - node_modules/
```

lambda.py :

```
from parser.utils import cleanPhoneNumber


def handle(event,context):
    number = event.get("number",None)
    return cleanPhoneNumber(number)
```

Running locally with serverless invoke local I get the following error :
`sls invoke local --function test -p event.json`

```
    module = import_module(args.handler_path.replace('/', '.'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/wuil/flynt/dev/delivery-service/services/visibility-extract/./lambda.py", line 1, in <module>
    from parser.utils import cleanPhoneNumber
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'parser.utils'; 'parser' is not a package
```

Any clue on why I am getting this ?
Thanks !

When only calling the lambda function without importing the modult it works just fine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.